# Unable to Open the Infopath in browser to Edit Items of Document library

Tags: infopath, forms-services, infopath-rules, infopath-data-connections, document-info-panel

- I am generating the code in one my sharepoint list,And creating the
  item in one of document library by adding the generated ID of the
  list.And document library is designed with infopath forms
- When I click on Infopath document it is opening in locally(desktop).But when I
  click on "New Document" in document library I am able to get the
  Infopath form in browser.

Can any one help me what is the issue and how can I solve this issue.

Comment: What's the SharePoint  version ? are you have installed InfoPath at your local machine ? what's the Infopath version ?

Comment: I am having the same issue on SharePoint 2013.  On a new item, opens up in the browser, however on an edit item, it opens up in InfoPath unless I specifically click on the elipse and then edit in browser, this is not how users will use it though, they will just click edit, which opens up the filler, how do we change this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the `Opening Documents in the Browser` has been set to  `Open in the browser`

- Go to the Form Library to which you published the InfoPath form template.
- From the above ribbon > Click Library setting > Advanced Setting
- On the Form Library Advanced Settings:  page under the Browser-enabled Documents category, choose `Open in the browser`

[image]

In some cases , you should Make Sure that the `SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection feature` has been activated at Site collection level. Also , try to republish your template again .

Comment: Have done both of these.  As stated, on new items it opens in browser, but on edit of an item it opens in the client, even with the "Open in Browser" Option being selected.